# How do you show dynamic code based on a dropdown in a persistent way with yii?

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I render some form elements when a dropdown is changed in yii, like so:

```
$form->dropdownListRow($model, 'type', array('item1','item2','etc') ,
    array('ajax'=>array(
        'type'=>'POST',
        'url'=>CController::createUrl('ProfileFieldRule/showAttributes'),
        'update'=>'#showAttributes',                        
    ))
));
```

ProfileFieldRule/showAttributes uses CHtml to render form elements, which leads to my first problem - I have to use opentag, etc and repeat work that's done in the form.

```
echo CHtml::openTag('div', array('class' => 'control-group '));
echo CHtml::activeLabel($attr, $name, array('class' => 'control-label'));
etc
```

The second problem is: if there is no change event (eg the forms submitted with errors) the dynamic content doesn't load.

I'm currently passing a model and checking if it's null, and otherwise doing the same rendering as in ProfileFieldRule/showAttributes eg:

```
   <div id="showAttributes">
    <?php if (isset($attr)) {
        //do the same rendering as in showAttributes
        $vars = get_class_vars(get_class($attr));
             foreach ($vars as $name => $value) {
                 //etc...
    ?>
    </div>
```

It would be *ideal* if I could just call the above code onload, onchange, and still have access to the $form.

I'm open to anything, so what's the best (or a good) solution to showing and persisting dynamic content as described above?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

### edit

Here's an image of what's happening https://i.stack.imgur.com/3u4Yb.jpg
*note, the rendered elements aren't showing ajax validation (highlighting in red/green) because I'm bad with ajax and still figuring*

I should note, that another solution I've considered is getting rid of showAttributes, continuing to pass two models to the form, and just calling the create action again on change.  This however gets rid of previous ajax validation when the dropdown is changed, as the entire form is redrawn.

Comment: I would suggest. If you need every time same elements then you can use jquery hide/show and keep the elements of same form if possible. then don't include form element dynamically. You could fetch the element value from ajax instead of whole element. Only put value in it using jquery. So you won't get any issues of binding event n all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need different elements based on the dropdown selection.

Comment: It seems you're updating dropdowns based on other dropdowns?   do the label and class change as well? If it's only the form options that change, I would just have my AJAX get the input element, and update that via jQuery.

Comment: I'm showing 3-5ish fields, not related, based on the dropdown.
Example: 
select item1, I show fields A,B,C
select item2, I show B,D,E,F,G
so for each field, I have to render the label, form element (textfield, etc).

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before as well.

The problem lies in the .bind('change'), you should use .live('change') instead,
In jQuery 1.7 this is solved by using the .on() function that does both live and normal binds.
Unforgettably Yii doesnt have the latest jQuery. For some projects i updated jQuery manually but keep in mid you will have to extend base classes to fix jQuery errors you'll get.
For a more direct and one time solution you could write a bit of js, that unbinds your events on the elements and then re-bind them with the .live() function.
But its all a bit hacky to say the least.